# Regex Extraction - Match before a space, or NOT before a space

Tags: regex

Here are my potential inputs:

1. `brian@muck.co, brian@gmail.com`
2. `brian@gmail.com, brian@muck.co`

What I want to do is extract the @muck.co email address.

What I have tried is:
`\s.*@muck.co`

The problem is that this *only* grabs an email address if it is preceded by a space (so it would only match the second example input above). . . How would I write a Regex expression to match either inputs?

Comment: Use `\S`, `\S+@muck\.co`

Comment: The comma (or beginning of string) is the natural delimiter here . Split using a regex `(?:^\s*|\s*,\s*)`

Answer (score 0):

`\s` matches for a space, so you should wanted to use something like `[^\s]*@muck.co` - this means any number of not space caracters. `[]` - for a set of symbols, `^` - for negate effect.

It does not work for me, because `\s` in my regex flavour seems to not contain regular space, but this works `[^[:space:]]\+@muck\.co`. Also `\+` instead of `*` for one or more non-space characters instead of any number and escape dot `\.` which unescaped stands for any single character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negated character class to not cross the @ and use either a word boundary at the end to prevent a partial word match:

```
[^\s@]+@muck\.co\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tWOvCa/1)